# copying files to another folder using bash

Tags: bash

I have a script that copies 1000 files to another folder. However, I have files that end with the following:

- *_LINKED_1.trees
- *_LINKED_2.trees
- *_LINKED_3.trees
- .
- .
- .
- *_LINKED_10.trees

'*' is not part of the name but there's some string in place of it.

What I want is to copy 1000 files for each of the types I've mentioned above in bullet points in a smart way.

```py
#!/bin/bash

for entry in /home/noor/popGen/sweeps/hard/final/*
do
    for i in {1..1000}
        do 
            cp $entry /home/noor/popGen/sweeps/hard/sample/hard
        done
done
```

Could there be a smart way to copy all 1000 files for each type? One way would be to have an if statement but I'll have to change that if- statement 10 times.

Comment: So you want to copy every file from `/home/noor/popGen/sweeps/hard/final/` to `/home/noor/popGen/sweeps/hard/sample/hard` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script below will do the required task.

```
file_count=0 
for i in {1..10};
do
for j in source/*_LINKED_$i.trees; 
    do
    file_count=$((file_count+1))
    echo "cp $j destination/"
    if ((file_count>1000)); 
        then    
            file_count=0
            break; 
    fi; 
done
done
```

Outer loop `for i in {1..10}` is used to mark the type of the files (`*_LINKED_$i.trees`).

Inner loop will iterate through all the files of each type (eg: `*_LINKED_1.trees`, `*_LINKED_2.trees` etc till `*_LINKED_10.trees`). Then it copies the first 1000 files (set using `file_count=1000`) into the destination for that particular type of file.

Comment: Thank you @j23 I'll try this :)